# Open template file in Pop Up

Tags: audio

I am trying to load a HTML5 Audio player in a popup but am having no luck. The staging site is [here](http://website-test-lab.com/sites/fm/)

The audio player works but not after you click the Listen In Pop Up button/link. Here is my code to call the template file which contains the same code as the on page audio section.

```
<a class="popup" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/inc/modules/module-audio-popup.php" 
onclick="javascript:void window.open('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/inc/modules/module-audio-popup.php',
'1418242983717','width=500,height=300,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');
return false;">
Listen in PopUp 
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="j"></span>
</a>
```

Any advice would be most welcome.

Code for the popup file [here](https://gist.github.com/huwrowlands/7390da51931e8e44688c)

Answer (score 0):

There is a fatal error in your source (`module-audio-popup.php`) :

> **Fatal error**: Call to undefined function `the_field()` in **/home/website/public_html/sites/fm/wp-content/themes/trickstarfm/assets/inc/modules/module-audio-popup.php** on line **11**

<sub>I will remove this *answer* later on, but posting this as a comment wouldn't make a readable post.</sub>

Comment: Yes; It appears that my custom meta field/s aren't working, my custom meta fields are via the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. This particular field is the src for the mp3 file. I am unsure how to fix this?

Comment: I suppose you didn't bootstrap WordPress in your custom PHP file...?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

`the_field()` function need a field name parameter and it must inside a loop.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/huwrowlands/7390da51931e8e44688c

Comment: OK, I think your code missing a few things: first, you need include wp-load.php for get_field() working; the second, you need include jQuery library plugin for call audioPlayer.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the tip to load wp-load.php

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860577/wordpress-wp-load-php) with this snippet:

```
if(!defined(ABSPATH)){
    $pagePath = explode('/wp-content/', dirname(__FILE__));
    include_once(str_replace('wp-content/' , '', $pagePath[0] . '/wp-load.php'));
}
```

I included this before any other HTML/PHP.